# Printing 100 to 200, with three exceptions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to write a  program that prints the numbers from 100 to 200, with three exceptions:

If the number is a multiple of 3, the string "yes" should be returned instead of the number.

If the number is a multiple of 4, the string "yes and yes" instead of the number should be returned.

If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 4, the string "yes, yes and yes" instead of the number.

I am new to JavaScript so I try to do this step by step.

I wrote this code to print the numbers from 100 to 200:

```
function hundredTwoHundred() {
  result = [];
  for (let i = 100; i <= 200; i++) {
  result.push(i);
}
  return result;
}

console.log(hundredTwoHundred());
```

Then I tried to use else/if for the exceptions:

```
function hundredTwoHundred() {
  result = [];
  for (let i = 100; i <= 200; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
    console.log("yes");
  } else if (i % 4 == 0) {
    console.log("yes and yes")
  } else if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 4 == 0) {
    console.log("yes, yes and yes");
  } else {
    result.push(i)
  }
}
  return result;
}

console.log(hundredTwoHundred());
```

The code of course, does not work. I have tried moving result.push(i) around, but I don't want to just mindlessly move things around, without knowing the reasoning behind it.

How do I use conditional operators to find these exceptions? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: do you like to push a value or text or log it immediately? the checks may be reordered from the most complex to a less complex check. so this comes first `i % 3 == 0 && i % 4 == 0` and then the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test if the number is (divisible by 3 *and* divisible by 4) *before* checking whether it's (individually) divisible by 3 or 4, otherwise the first condition `if (i % 3 == 0)` will evaluate to `true` and you'll get `yes` rather than `yes, yes and yes`. You should also `push` to the `result` in the conditionals rather than `console.log`ging in the conditionals, since you want to create an *array* of numbers and `yes`es and then `console.log` the whole constructed array *afterwards*.

Also make sure to declare the `result` with `const` (or `var`, for ES5) - it's not good to implicitly create global variables.

Also, although it doesn't matter in *this* case, when comparing, it's good to rely on `===` by default rather than `==` - best to only use `==` when you deliberately want to rely on implicit type coercion, which can result in confusing behavior.

```js
function hundredTwoHundred() {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 100; i <= 200; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 4 === 0) {
      result.push("yes, yes and yes");
    } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
      result.push("yes");
    } else if (i % 4 === 0) {
      result.push("yes and yes")
    } else {
      result.push(i)
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(hundredTwoHundred());
```

Answer (score 2):

If a number is a multiple of 3 and 4, then it is a multiple of 12. I’d also use a switch statement, so you can rewrite as follow:

```
for (let i = 100; i <= 200; i = i + 1) {
  switch (0) {
    case i % 12: console.log('yes, yes and yes'); break;
    case i % 4:  console.log('yes and yes'); break;
    case i % 3:  console.log('yes'); break;
    default:     console.log(i);
  }
}
```

If you want it as an array:

```
// Fill an array with numbers from 100 to 200
const arr = Array(101).fill().map((_, i) => i + 100);

// Map it to numbers and strings
const hundredTwoHundred = arr.map(i => {
  switch (0) {
    case i % 12: return 'yes, yes and yes';
    case i % 4:  return 'yes and yes';
    case i % 3:  return 'yes';
    default:     return i
  }
});

// Print it:
console.log(hundredTwoHundred);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a complex set of conditions you need to be careful with the order in which you evaluate them.

```
function logExceptions(start, end) {
    var divisibleByThree, divisibleByFour;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
        divisibleByThree = i % 3 == 0;
        divisibleByFour = i % 4 == 0;
        if (divisibleByThree && divisibleByFour) {
            console.log("yes, yes and yes");
        }
        else if (divisibleByThree) {
            console.log("yes");
        }
        else if (divisibleByFour) {
            console.log("yes and yes");
        }
        else {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
logExceptions(100, 200);
```

If you want to save the result in an array and only later print it:

```
function logExceptions(start, end) {
    var result = [];
    var divisibleByThree, divisibleByFour;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
        divisibleByThree = i % 3 == 0;
        divisibleByFour = i % 4 == 0;
        if (divisibleByThree && divisibleByFour) {
            result.push("yes, yes and yes");
        }
        else if (divisibleByThree) {
            result.push("yes");
        }
        else if (divisibleByFour) {
            result.push("yes and yes");
        }
        else {
            result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(logExceptions(100, 200).toString());
```